# What will happen If we update Interval time for the PeriodicWorkRequest while releasing next version?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Let's Imagine, I have an app it uses PeriodicWorkRequest with delay of 1 day, now I am updating the delay days from 1 day to 7 days and releasing next version. can anyone please tell me that what will happen for this case?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyTzr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNhxW.png)